# Using active directory as a master staff database and allowing specific users edit capability

Tags: active-directory, user-management, monitoring

We have a challenge in our enterprise, where we have at least a few different storage locations for employee information.  We are trying to get this all consolidated as much as possible so there is one place to go and look up / edit employee information such as name, address and phone number.

Since 90+% of employees have active directory accounts, we are thinking AD is a good place to make the master source of information - to pull from there / make edits there.

The rest will be updated / pulled from a second HR system (the HR system is limited however, and not user friendly for MIS or other non HR staff to go in and out of and make edits on a regular basis).  These are employees that are short term and most likely not worth the effort of constantly editing by MIS.

So, I am looking for suggestions on how to allow certain key users (specific managers or HR staff for example) to be given access to some sort of utility or interface to edit active directory users (or possibly even add them if possible).

However, I of course do not want to allow any non MIS staff to be able to edit the access information such as group memberships.  They should only be able to edit personal information such as name, address, phones and similar.

One possibility I am looking at is SpiceWorks - I already use it, and synchronize with AD.  I know it has an ability to write changes back to AD, so maybe that will work.  Anyone else use SpiceWorks, or any other utility to do this (or have other suggestions)?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to delegate `Modify` or `write` to specific attributes. You can do this through the Active Directory Delegation Wizard. You would make a group for HR and delegate the appropriate permissions to them. They would then be able to edit the info using ADUC or you could write a custom web interface, which isn't all that difficult to do if you don't want them to use ADUC for some reason.

Comment: Thanks.  I managed to get the ADUC utility installed on an XP machine, used the delegation wizard on a container with users, but I can not seem to enable edit or the basic user information.  Do you happen to know what the permissions are called for that information - for example, phones or address?   I enabled the 'public' information, 'phones', and a couple other similar sounding properties, but those screens are still gray.

Comment: @ScottSzretter http://www.kouti.com/tables/userattributes.htm or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675090%28v=vs.85%29.aspx are both useful.

Answer (score -1):

Well, seriously-  whoever thinks AD is a good source database to run your central HR information is someone you should get a ercomendation... one to work for your competitor (a.k.a. fire him).

It is way too low level and technical to b a logical business side master system.

I think the approach is brkoen - you will end up doping tons of setup for little gain. AD is very technical, you need a higher level logical application.

Comment: I do not think I am asking for it to be our 'central HR information' database, but the issue we have is a central place for peoples name, address and phone numbers.   We have PDF's produced from the 'HR database' on a file server or on peoples local machines that they downloaded, a web site with an outdated document, people use exchange/outlook and look up information from there, and even more sources.   We are trying to eliminate this from the point of view of most of our users use outlook and they can look people up in there.  Plus we can generate pdf's / reports off AD if needed.

Comment: That makesm ore sense. In this case, though, I would automate the AD information storage via a nightly batch from the HR application. And / or use SQL Server Master Data Services to craete and maintain a central truth location. The later ist he most professional approach - starting a central enterpris data model (for HR) that other systems feed from.